# MySQL match values in IN clause to every group value

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL table:

```
id   value
1    a
1    b
2    b
2    c
3    c
```

I want to query this table and get all the ids whose group matched elements in the MySQL `IN` clause.

For example, if I provide `IN("a", "b", "x", "z")`, I want to return `1` because every row in `1` (group 1) matches the values I provided in the clause.

How can this be done?

Comment: I wonder if you were too hasty to accept the first  answer provided

Comment: if you have a better answer ill change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting problem if I understood it correctly.

This approach checks the aggregate `COUNT()` of each `id` when limited by the `IN ()` list against the total `COUNT()` aggregate of each `id` when not limited by a `WHERE` clause at all.  If the two counts match, it is because every `value` associated with the `id` was matched in your `IN ()` list.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tlimit.id 
FROM 
  ( 
     -- A subquery to get the *limited* count per id
     SELECT id, COUNT(tbl.id) as limitc
     FROM tbl
     WHERE value IN ('a','b','x','z')
     GROUP BY tbl.id
  ) tlimit 
  INNER JOIN (
     -- A subquery to get the *total* count per id
     SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS total FROM tbl GROUP BY id
  ) tcount 
    -- Join the total count per id against the limited count
    -- so the query only returns rows where they're exactly equal
    ON tlimit.id = tcount.id
    AND tlimit.limitc = tcount.total
```

Here it is in action, with an additional `id = 4` that should be returned: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6aa0a/1

Comment: What if `IN("a", "b", "c")`?

Comment: @CahitGungor In that case, I think all ids `1,2,3` would be returned because for each of them, all rows would match the `IN ()`. If that is not the requirement, the OP can clarify.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for